# Fedora client persist old address after router advertisement

Tags: router, avahi, radvd

I have a linux-based DSL router, running radvd
Because the prefix from my ISP may change, so I have to change the radvd.conf when prefix changes. For example, like this.

```
interface br-lan
{
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    MinRtrAdvInterval 20;
    MaxRtrAdvInterval 60;
    prefix 2001:db8:aaaa:1::/64
    {
        AdvOnLink on;
        AdvAutonomous on;
        AdvRouterAddr off;
        DeprecatePrefix on;
        AdvPreferredLifetime 86400;
        AdvValidLifetime 1000000;
    };
};
```

But something went wrong on one of my fedora (Fedora29, recently yum updated) notebook.

It persist using 2001:db8:aaaa:1::/64 prefix even the prefix has changed to 2001:db8:aaaa:2::/64, like this:

```
$ ip a s dev wlp1s0
3: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.64/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp1s0
       valid_lft 63097sec preferred_lft 63097sec
    inet6 2001:db8:aaaa:1:830f:530c:7d46:ad33/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 929545sec preferred_lft 15945sec
    inet6 2001:db8:aaaa:2:db4e:debc:4e36:9c1d/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 999970sec preferred_lft 86370sec
    inet6 fe80::a8aa:aaff:feaa:aaaa/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The old & deprecated & bad address is even preferred, and will be used as source address when connecting to a remote ipv6 endpoint, and will fail.
I can delete the deprecated address manually by `ip a d ... dev wlp1s0`, but it comes back after a router-advertisement package, even the package is correct and the valid_lft of deprecated address not increased. Some logs were found in /var/log/message:

```
Dec 18 21:40:28 fedora avahi-daemon[835]: Withdrawing address record for 2001:db8:aaaa:1:830f:530c:7d46:ad33 on wlp1s0.
Dec 18 21:41:16 fedora avahi-daemon[835]: Registering new address record for 2001:db8:aaaa:1:830f:530c:7d46:ad33 on wlp1s0.*.
```

Other devices in the same network, two windows10 clients and one CentOS7 works fine.

Comment: Are you sure your router isn't advertising both prefixes?

Comment: I'm sure. I've checked the icmp6 packages by tcpdump.